# Doctrine ORM Admin adding placeholder to datagrid filter

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there any way to add a place holder to a filter on the Sonata Doctrine ORM Admin?

I'm trying to something like this:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagrid)
{
    $datagrid->add('number', null, ['label' => 'User Pin', 
                                    'attr'  => [
                                           'placeholder' => '####',
                                           'title' => 'Enter the 4 digits pin'
                                           ]
                                   ]
                  );
}
```

Note that this is just an excerpt of the working code.

I'm expecting/needing to have a placeholder on the input field, and perhaps a tooltip with the title attribute.

Is this possible? Hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me :

```
        ->add
        (
            'number', 
            null,
            [
                'label' => 'User Pin',
            ],
            null,
            [
                'attr'  => 
                [
                    'placeholder' => '####',
                    'title' => 'Enter the 4 digits pin'
                ]
            ]
        )
```

The 5th parameter represents the field options, the 3rd represents the filter options.